# Facebook Messenger: How to access "last active" time of friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to build an app that displays the information when a particular friend was last active simply by pulling it from your messenger app if an fb api access token has been granted.

But..does anyone know how to get this information because unless I missed it, facebook doesn't have a specific API call for it. Any recommendations on how I might go about pulling this data in a custom way? I know that anyone logged into the messenger app on either mobile and/or messenger.com has access to this data for their friend's list.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I dont think the SDK exposes that information in anyway.

Comment: Right, I don't think it does otherwise I would have found it myself. I'm wondering if there's any way to ping for that information though that's why I asked. Any suggestions for how I would start going about creating a custom API for that field by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out now since in the newest web application version facebook has placed the last active time in the header of the chat name. On messenger.com this can be easily parsed out by your favorite library like BeautifulSoup or scrapey etc.